# How access app widget when screen locked

Tags: android, widget, locking, screen

I have designed app widget Music player and working successfully but i want to access my app even when android screen is locked.Is it possible.If yes can u help me to get through this.

Thanks in Advance
Regards-Sasi

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of what you mean by "access my app even when android screen is locked".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to put your code into a service. Services allow your code to run even when the screen is locked rather than activities which will unfortunately be put into a lifecycle event where they can no longer execute the code.

Post some code and we will help you to make this move.

Comment: Thanks for ur Valuable Response.

Answer (score 0):

To access your widgets from the application (from the lock screen), you can use the services.

Like that: **BigBalanceAppWidgetProvider.java**

```
public class BigBalanceAppWidgetProvider extends BaseAppWidgetProvider {
    public static final String TAG = "BigBalanceAppWidgetProvider";
    ...
    public static void updateAppWidget(Context context,
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId,
            User appWidgetUser, Boolean error) {
        RemoteViews views;
        ... 
    }
    ...
}
```

Call it from service: **WidgetUpdateBalanceService.java**

```
public class WidgetUpdateBalanceService extends IntentService {
    ...
    private void doSingleUpdate() {
        BigBalanceAppWidgetProvider.updateAppWidget(mContext, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, user);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Widgets on the lock screen are available for Android 4.2+ devices only. Information on how to achieve this can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#Lockscreen) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen)

Comment: Thanks for ur Valuable Response